# Do the settings stored in IntelliJ settings repository contain usernames and passwords

Tags: git, intellij-idea, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I want to share my IntelliJ settings on a public GIT repo using IntelliJ's Settings Repository feature.  I need to verify that no sensitive data like usernames, passwords, SSH Keys are transferred in these settings.  Can anyone verify that or point me in the direction of documentation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, Settings Repository doesn't contain sensitive information. I am developer of this plugin and my working repo is public — https://github.com/develar/__intellij_settings (so, you can be sure that my answer is not just "marketing").

But JetBrains is not responsible for 3rd-party plugins, so, if you use non-JetBrains plugins, it is better to inspect settings repo commits after such plugin installation.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for responding and putting my mind at ease.  I definitely understand about third party plugins and their risks.  Again... thanks.

Comment: I use IntelliJ 2017.2.5 and noticed that passwords of my configured clouds (heroku, cloud foundry) were indeed synced in plain text to the git repository. @develar - is this a bug? This cloud plugin is developed by jetbrains itself. Seeing this i would be really careful using this feature in intellij.